# When transferring value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

When transferring value within a function which one is best practices to do?

`require(refundAddresses[x].send(refunds[refundAddresses[x]]))`

```
refundAddresses[x].send(refunds[refundAddresses[x]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is an "unchecked" send, meaning the return value (bool) isn't checked.

So, the first one.

You can also do:

`refundAddresses[x].transfer(refunds[refundAddresses[x]]);`

... which will revert on failure, so does the check and reacts for you.

It looks suspiciously like part of an iterative process, e.g. `for(x=0; x< ...`. Don't do it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: off topic, hope you will answer :) 
The operator used in mappings '=>' if this operator is used without spaces applied, will it then be understood as equal or larger than? e.g

mapping(address => uint) public xx
mapping(address=>uint) public yy

Comment: No, it's just a syntax for saying the DHT maps an address to an unsigned integer. So `uint y = xx[address]` is the integer stored my an address. I never found a really good explainer for mappings, so I might turn your attention to "Basic Tools - Mappings" in this blog: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a

Comment: but this syntax has the same meaning regardless if written like this (x address=>uint) or (address => uint) the space between the syntax does not change the context?

Comment: The spaces are unimportant. `mapping(x address=>uint) myMap` doesn't compile. The format is `mapping(indexType => variableType) variableName` and you can add the `public` modifier for a "free" getter, with some limitations.